# RXjava and Retrofit to handle empty data response

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I use Rxjava and Retrofit to handle the response from an HTTP server.

Most of the time, data response is in this format:

```
{
  code: 'OK',
  data: {.....}
}
```

And sometimes, the `data` property doesn't exist:

```
{
  code: 'OK'
}
```

I make a `BaseResponse` class.

```
public class BaseResponse<T> implements Serializable {
    private String code;
    private String msg;
    private T data;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

And make a `Map` function to parse it:

```
public static <T> Function<BaseResponse<T>, T> applyUnwrapResponse () {
        return new Function<BaseResponse<T>, T>() {
            @Override
            public T apply(@NonNull BaseResponse<T> baseResponse) throws Exception {
                if (baseResponse.getCode().equals(Constants.SUCCESS_CODE)) {
                    // http returned from server
                    T data = baseResponse.getData();
                    if (data == null) {
                        return null;  // throw exception: The mapper function returned a null value
                        return return new T(); // syntax error
                        // how ?
                    }
                    return data;
                } else if (baseResponse.getCode().equals(Constants.USER_NOT_LOGGED_IN)) {
                    // auth token error
                    throw new UserNotLoginException(baseResponse.getMsg());
                }
                // unknown error
                throw new UnknownServerException(baseResponse.getMsg());
            }
        };
    }
```

When `data` property doesn't exist, I try to return `null`, but this is not allowed in [Rxjava2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#nulls).
In the customize Observer, I handle all `success` scenarios in onNext(), so I need to emit an error when `data == null`.
but I can not return null, and also cannot return a `T` by `return new T()`, so how should I do? Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several suggested options:

- As Gson parser will put null in fields with no data, so you can return the entire `BaseResponse` object and check the nullity of data property object at the Subscriber/Observer.
- You can simply wrap your T value with some `Optional` alike interface, which can have a value, or can have nothing (Java8 `Optional` probably not available with android, but you can come up with simple structure like `Optional` yourself), then on your `onNext()` you can check whether you have a value or not.
- RxJava2 has new `Observable` type called [Maybe](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html), which either emit a single item - `onSuccess` notification, or nothing - `onComplete()` notification, (and also errors):

  ```
  onSubscribe (onSuccess | onCompleted | onError)?
  ```

  You can use `flatMapMaybe` with both `Observable` or `Single` (from the Retrofit service interface), to map some response value to a `Maybe`, in the `flatMapMaybe` you can use `Maybe.fromCallable` to return null like you did here,  `Maybe.fromCallable` will treat returned null as no items emitted, and you'll get `onComplete()`, so you can distinguish between result case (`onNext`) to the no items case (`onComplete`).

Comment: the option1 seems better for me. but can it work with Retrofit and  Gson?  I mean can Gson convert response correctly when the `data` property is `Optional`.

Comment: I didn't mean that the parser will do it, I meant that you will do the same logic you applied here but instead of return null return optional with no value.

Comment: actually Gson parser put null at data when there is nothing in the response, so you can basically return the entire `BaseResponse` object and check the nullity of data property object at the Subscriber/Observer

Comment: Yeah, Maybe I should use this map function in this scenario, and should just let Observer to handle it.

Comment: I've added this option as well to the answer

Comment: Thanks, good answer. for me [Maybe](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html) was the best solution